# Why does my parallel merge algorithm produce the correct values in all positions of the output except the first?

Tags: algorithm, merge, concurrency, rust, parallel-processing

I am writing a parallel merging algorithm in Rust using `scoped-threadpool`, but it seems to be producing the correct values in all positions of the output except the first.

I am attempting to adapt the pseudocode from the merge algorithm [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm#Parallel_merge):

```
fn parallel_merge(first: &[i32], second: &[i32], output: &mut [i32]) {
    let mut n = first.len();
    let mut m = second.len();
    let a;
    let b;

    // Make sure that 'first' is the largest of the two to be merged
    if m < n {
        a = first;
        b = second;
    } else {
        a = second;
        b = first;

        let tmp = n;
        n = m;
        m = tmp;
    }

    if m <= 0 {
        return;
    }

    let pivot = n / 2;
    let s = bisect(a[pivot], b);
    let t = pivot + s;

    output[t] = a[pivot];

    let mut pool = Pool::new(2);
    pool.scoped(|scoped| {
        let (left, right) = output.split_at_mut(t);
        scoped.execute(move || {
            parallel_merge(&a[..pivot], &b[..s], left);
        });

        scoped.execute(move || {
            parallel_merge(&a[pivot..], &b[s..], right);
        });
    });
}
```

When called with `first` as the slice `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`, `second` as `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]` and a slice of ten zeroes as the initial output, `output` is left as `[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

What is going wrong? As far as I can see, it matches the pseudocode aside from the unnecessary tracking of indexes.

Comment: Did you tried to test algorithm without treading?
If it fails, try to use debugger for this, I use Visual Studio debugger for this.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, functions etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: *a slice of ten zeroes*, *output is left as [an array of nine values]*. These aren't compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misread the algorithm. `m` is the length of `A`:

```
algorithm merge(A[i...j], B[k...ℓ], C[p...q]) is

    let m = j - i,
        n = ℓ - k
```

You have it as the length of `B`:

```rust
let mut m = second.len();
```

The complete example:

```
use scoped_threadpool::Pool; // 0.1.9

fn parallel_merge(a: &[i32], b: &[i32], output: &mut [i32]) {
    let (a, b) = if a.len() >= b.len() { (a, b) } else { (b, a) };

    if a.is_empty() {
        return;
    }

    let pivot = a.len() / 2;
    let s = match b.binary_search(&a[pivot]) {
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(x) => x,
    };
    let t = pivot + s;

    let (a_left, a_tail) = a.split_at(pivot);
    let (a_mid, a_right) = a_tail.split_first().unwrap();

    let (b_left, b_right) = b.split_at(s);

    let (o_left, o_tail) = output.split_at_mut(t);
    let (o_mid, o_right) = o_tail.split_first_mut().unwrap();

    *o_mid = *a_mid;

    let mut pool = Pool::new(2);
    pool.scoped(|scoped| {
        scoped.execute(move || parallel_merge(a_left, b_left, o_left));
        scoped.execute(move || parallel_merge(a_right, b_right, o_right));
    });
}

#[test]
fn exercise() {
    let first = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
    let second = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
    let mut output = [0; 10];

    parallel_merge(&first, &second, &mut output);
    assert_eq!(output, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
}
```